# Adapter call is getting failed (Time out) every time at first call

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

While developing the Android fully hybrid app , we have observed that this adapter call is getting a failure (time out) every time at first call. I am adding a screenshot for it[image: Time out issue in android at first call]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwP7.png): [image: Time out issue at first call to the adapter]

We have also increased the timeout property in initOption.js like `timeout: 6000000` but doens't work.
We have also set timeout at adapter level like `<procedure name="GetAPICall" requestTimeoutInSeconds="60"/>` but it doesn't work either.

My Observation : I don't think at the time of this issue the request is reaching the server.  The app should wait for 60 seconds for a response, but this timeout we are getting instantly after hitting the adapter.

Comment: Does the adapter times out only on the first call (and then it works ever after)? Do you have other adapters that work? What is the Worklight version? Is the adapter protected? One suggestion: Monitor the network traffic with a sniffing tool like Wireshark and observe what happens under the hood.

Comment: It is only happening in first call to adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your device can communicate with the Worklight Server where you have deployed your application and adapter(s). An easy way to test this is to go into the phones mobile browser and attempt to connect to the Worklight console at a location in the form of the following:

http://"server address":"port"/"context root"/console

If your application cannot connect to the console successfully it is likely your device is not on the correct wifi network in order to establish communication. Please attempt this connection and provide an update so we can provide further investigation. As for your observation I would agree that the request is never making it to the server and that is why the 60 second timeout is not occurring.

Comment: Hi @jaalger, I am stuck with an issue and was wondering if you could help me. When trying to authenticate the user using the submitAdapterAuthentication() and the app is not able to connect to the worklight server, I get the timout message in the console but there is not callback to handle the timeout. Can you let me know what can be done to catch this?

Comment: @vshall can you open a new question with more details please